# module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__' when importing Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

This issue occurs at Jupyter Notebook and Visual Studio Code, and I spent about 3 hours trying to find a solution from different previous stackoverflows questions, I tried installing and uninstalling both numpy and pandas, and the issue keeps reappearing. On Visual Studio Code I installed and unisntalled multiple times both Numpy and Pandas. There seems to be no problem with importing numpy, but fails to import pandas. Please help:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

results in:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\apodo\Downloads\Untitled.py in line 2
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import pandas as pd

File c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:36
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     32 del _hard_dependencies, _dependency, _missing_dependencies
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     34 try:
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     35     # numpy compat
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:1'>1</a>;32m---> 36     from pandas.compat import (
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     37         is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev,  # pyright: ignore[reportUnusedImport] # noqa: F401,E501
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     38     )
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     39 except ImportError as _err:  # pragma: no cover
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     40     _module = _err.name

File c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:27
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     25 import pandas.compat.compressors
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     26 from pandas.compat.numpy import is_numpy_dev
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:1'>1</a>;32m---> 27 from pandas.compat.pyarrow import (
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     28     pa_version_under7p0,
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     29     pa_version_under8p0,
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     30     pa_version_under9p0,
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     31     pa_version_under11p0,
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:0'>0</a>;32m     32     pa_version_under13p0,
...
ref='c:\Users\apodo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pyarrow.py:1'>1</a>;32m---> 10     _palv = Version(Version(pa.__version__).base_version)
     11     pa_version_under7p0 = _palv < Version("7.0.0")
     12     pa_version_under8p0 = _palv < Version("8.0.0")

AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: your title isn't consistent with the error message, is it meant to say: `module 'pyarrow' has no attribute '__version__'`?

Comment: It looks like namespace pollution. What do you get when doing the same import in a terminal (same python executable)?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install --upgrade pyarrow`?

Comment: @Nin17 Yes sorry my bad just updated the title

Comment: @Learning is a mess interestingly enough I just got a new response which didn't happen before, it says "conda: The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cdmlet, function, script file..." in VS Code and the response I showed in the original post when I type it in Jupyter.

Comment: I meant that the title says 'numpy' has no attribute ... whereas the error message is about 'pyarrow'

Comment: @Malcolm Thanks that did something so the error no longer appears, however now returning that the term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

Comment: Does the new error happen on the `import pandas as pd` line?

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks a lot for all help. I did your suggestions and realized that I should just try to reinstall Python all together, and that seemed to work.